# Macbook2,1 late 2006 fan not spinning

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, temperature

My macbook is very hot, the fan never starts. I tried some softwares like Fan Control 1.2, scmfancontrol 2.4 and Macs Fan Control but each of them is giving me always 0 rpm on the main (right) fan…

Why? What can I do?

The system is a very fresh install of Lion, updated to the last, 10.7.5

Ps: I remember that before going to reinstall it, a manual control on the fan was working...

Answer (score 1):

Zero for fan speed can be often a sign phisical damage of a fan or its connector. If resetting of SMC won't help, then it is what I said.

Comment: Update: MacBook Pro 13 2015 switches off the fan when idle, so this is currently the only case when zero doesn't indicate an error.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reset the SMC on a MacBook with removable battery

1. Shutdown and disconnect your charger
2. Remove the battery.
3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds, then release.
4. Connect the charger and press the power button to turn your Mac back on.

#### Reset NVRAM

1. Shutdown.
2. Boot whilst holding ⇧⌥PR until the second chime.

Comment: It does boot… I am holding left shift, ctrl, alt and power button..

How much long should I hold them?

Comment: @elect Ah, the 2006 MacBook has a removable battery, right? The process is different for computers with removable batteries — see edited answer.

Comment: I did that too, no success.. How can I know if I successfully reset the SMC? May the nvram reset help too?

Comment: @elect There's no way to tell if SMC worked afaik. Sure, NVRAM reset may do it. (Added to answer if anyone else comes across this in the future.)

Comment: It doesnt work, what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If one attempt at resetting the SMC didn't revive the fan, then I would say the fan has failed and you will need to reseat the fan cable or replace the fan to tell if it's the fan itself or something on the logic board that has failed.

Also, before spending money, I would try installing a clean OS X onto a USB stick or SD card just to be sure it's not software or the SMC modification tools you have installed that are causing the issue. Unlikely, but you'd hate to spend money on a software issue.